# Java config to XML config - Spring Social

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-social

I'm new to Java Config & am stuggling to convert a piece of Java based config to XML based config.
Can anyone kindly guide me with the conversion. Many thanks!

```
@Bean
@Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES) 
public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
    JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(
        dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator(), Encryptors.noOpText());
    repository.setConnectionSignUp(new AccountConnectionSignUp(accountRepository));
    return repository;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found out myself:

```
<bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="jpaDataSource" />
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
        <property name="connectionSignUp" ref="accountConnectionSignUp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accountConnectionSignUp" class="path to AccountConnectionSignUp" />
```

This is for anyone's help. Thanks!